# how to modify columun time format

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have several files with a datetime in one column and I'm trying to change the time from '%hh.%nn.%ss' to '%hh:%nn:%ss'.
the difficulty is that the position of the TIME column changes depending on the file
example

```
1-File 1:
22;23243;1;2013-08-23-15.46.34;

2- File 2 :
0000054;0000001;00496999999;0000;2012-02-29-13.40.18;001
```

Thank you

sed in  unix command to solve the problem

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output (corresponding to the provided sample inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(....-..-..-..)\.(..)\.(..)/\1:\2:\3/' file
```

Pattern match and use back references to replace `.`'s by `:`'s.

Answer (score 0):

> difficulty is that the position of the TIME column changes depending
> on the file example

You need *heuristic* to determine if given column hold TIME or not, considering your sample input I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
22;23243;1;2013-08-23-15.46.34;
0000054;0000001;00496999999;0000;2012-02-29-13.40.18;001
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if($i~/\y[0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9]\y/){gsub(/[.]/,":",$i)}};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
22;23243;1;2013-08-23-15:46:34;
0000054;0000001;00496999999;0000;2012-02-29-13:40:18;001
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) is semicolon, then for each line I iterate over fields using `for` loop if given column contain substring looking like TIME then I replace all `.` in it with `:`. Said substring is whole word `dd.dd.dd` where `d` is digit and `.` is dot, `\y` is [word-boundary](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) and prevent reaction to substrings having more digits than legal for TIME e.g. `130.00.00`, observe that `.` has special meaning in regex, so I use `[.]` which means literal dot.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*